# JAVAMAILSMTP error

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am using javamail tp send emails.I hava added the javamail and JAF libraries to my project.but when i run it from websphere in RAD 7.0 i am getting the following error.

```
    2/16/12 19:16:15:445 IST] 00000026 SystemOut     O DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "webmail.emailmyname.com", port 25, isSSL false
[2/16/12 19:16:17:437 IST] 00000026 SystemOut     O Exiting MailServlet
[2/16/12 19:16:17:430 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: webmail.emailmyname.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[2/16/12 19:16:17:430 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:430 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:430 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:430 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:430 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:430 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:431 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:431 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.devx.example.MailServlet.doPost(MailServlet.java:64)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:431 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:431 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:431 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1449)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:431 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:431 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:431 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:431 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:431 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:432 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:432 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:432 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
[2/16/12 19:16:17:432 IST] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(H
```

Answer (score 0):

Wither your server is down or configured to run on a different port . You can issue "telnet webmail.emailmyname.com 25" , if you get a response back "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused" then chances  are that your server is configured on a different port  (You can also verify whether your server is down by issuing "ping webmail.emailmyname.com " ).

Comment: Then is 25 the correct port number ? do you get a response on issuing a telnet on that port ?